# Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

when trying to add a fragment to my class i keep getting this error im not sure how to fix this im pretty sure im adding the fragment right but the error keeps appearing and crashing my app when i try to run it any idea how to fix it?

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ericvuu.whatsfordinner.RecipeActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.ericvuu.whatsfordinner.RecipeActivity"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recipe1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="484dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recipe2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipe1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recipe3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-11dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipe2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java file

```
 package com.example.ericvuu.whatsfordinner;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public Button recipeText;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

             recipeText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recipe1);


                try {
                    String message;
                    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("RecipeText");
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(message + "\n");
                    }
                    recipeText.setText(sb.toString());

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

    }
```

and the landscape xml file im triyng to put the fragment in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/layout_default"
        android:name="com.example.ericvuu.whatsfordinner.RecipeActivity"
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.08" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `RecipeActivity` is an `Activity`. It is not a `Fragment`. You cannot treat it as a `Fragment`. Also, whenever you get an `InflateException`, you need to look further on in the stack trace for the actual cause. The `InflateException` itself doesn't tell you much.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding fragment in xml for vertical and landscape mode. So once when you launch your app it will crash because you already have added fragment in your activity. I would recommend better try adding fragment using container.

ex:-
put this line in your xml

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

instead of adding direct fragment into xml.

and try adding your fragment programmatically.

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 .......
 ......
```

And also check RecipeActivity is an activity not fragment. this code works only with fragment

Comment: do i put that in the landscape xml?

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeM. tell in the comment, you can't use an Activity for `android:name` attribute inside fragment tag.

The [Fragments documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) says:

> The android:name attribute in the  specifies the Fragment
>   class to instantiate in the layout.

So, you can't use the following:

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.ericvuu.whatsfordinner.RecipeActivity"/>
```

You need to convert your `RecipeActivity` activity to Fragment.